# R Scatterplot/bubble chart with dot size based on observation number

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, scatter-plot, bubble-chart

I know this question has been *somewhat* answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579995/control-the-size-of-points-in-an-r-scatterplot#2580113), [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/ggplot2-cheatsheet-for-scatterplots/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26757026/bubble-chart-with-ggplot2).

In all of these examples the dot/bubble size is based on a third factor such as `size`.

However, in my data, I only have 2 variables, `xval` and `yval`.

```
library("ggplot2")
xval <- c("0","0.5","0.25","0","0")
yval <- c("1","0.5","0.25","0.25","1")
df.test <- data.frame(xval,yval)
df.test
p <- ggplot(df.test, aes(x = xval, y = yval)) + geom_point()
p
```

Here is `df.test`

```
  xval yval
1    0    1
2  0.5  0.5
3 0.25 0.25
4    0 0.25
5    0    1
```

and here is `p`

[image]

What I would like is **each dot/bubble size to depend on the number of occurrence of the observations of this coordinate.** For instance, (0,1) would be to be twice as big as the others dots. I would like to avoid adding a 3rd column to my data frame, and leaving R doing it automatically.

I don't know if this can be done without having to play too much with the data... Any insight would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Why would (0,1) be twice as big as the others if it's the 5th observation? Do you want the size to be different for each observation?

Comment: @Warner see my edit :) (0,1) occurs twice, and all the others once, so the dot would be twice bigger.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `geom_count()`

```
xval <- c("0","0.5","0.25","0","0")
yval <- c("1","0.5","0.25","0.25","1")
df.test <- data.frame(xval,yval)
df.test

ggplot(df.test, aes(x = xval, y = yval)) + geom_count()
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! `geom_count`, I was missing this one :)