# Lable specific points of geom_jitter() by using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, jitter

when using this code:

```
t1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(cyl),y=mpg))
t2 <- geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA)
t3 <- geom_jitter(width=0.3, size=1.5, aes(color = disp))
t4 <- scale_colour_gradient(low="blue",high="red")
t5 <- geom_text(aes(label=ifelse(mpg > 30,as.character(mpg),'')))

t1 + t2 + t3 + t4 + t5
```

I get a boxplot in combination with jitter points. I am also able to label the points of interest, however: the labeling is not next to the specific point, but rather in the vertical middle of the boxplot.

[Here is the figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ptmC.png)

Any idea how I can place the text next to the corresponding point?

Thank you a lot guys!

By the way: can you recommend me a course or a tutorial for ggplot2 beginners?

Comment: This topic must give you some hints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551147/adding-text-to-ggplot-geom-jitter-points-that-match-a-condition

Comment: I have a question on you choice of plot. How should one read the horizontal jittering of points given that the x-axis is a factor with 4,6 and 8 as the only unique values? Just curious!1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jitter it beforehand?

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
t1 <- ggplot(transform(mtcars, xjit=jitter(as.numeric(as.factor(cyl)))), aes(x=as.factor(cyl),y=mpg))
t2 <- geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA)
t3 <- geom_point(size=1.5, aes(x=xjit, color = disp))
t4 <- scale_colour_gradient(low="blue",high="red")
t5 <- geom_text(aes(x=xjit, label=ifelse(mpg > 30,as.character(mpg),'')), vjust = 1)

t1 + t2 + t3 + t4 + t5
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you lukeA. As I still consider myself as a beginner in R, I have to ask you about some changes in the code you made. Can you please tell me why you used transform in the t1 line, and what is transform doing acutally to the remaining code? I also do not understand what xjit is, and what in the t3 line color = disp does (what is disp)? Sorry for all the questions...

Comment: Sure. I used `transform` to create a new column `xjit` on the fly, i.e. just for the plot, without storing another variable somewhere in the R environment. `xjit` is the _jit_'tered _x_-value. `color=disp` comes from your example - it maps the column `disp` to the color aesthetics.