# How to label the outliers of boxplot with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

My data is as follows:

```
genes   fc   type
349028  -1.2 pro
2454    1.1  pro
24908   0.4  pro
4730    0.8  pro
94988   0.9  pro
9865    6    pro
8935    3.4  phos
39280   1.2  phos
8034    -0.3 phos
3953    1.1  phos
4732    2.1  phos
```

I want to label the outliers of boxplot with ggplot2 and plot all the points with "jitter", but the outlier appear twice. My code is as follows:

```html
pathdata=read.table(file="data.txt",header=TRUE,quote="",sep="\t")
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
is_outlier <- function(x) {
  return(x < quantile(x, 0.25) - 1.5 * IQR(x) | x > quantile(x, 0.75) + 1.5 * IQR(x))
}
pathdata %>%
 group_by(type) %>%
 mutate(outlier=ifelse(is_outlier(fc),genes,as.numeric(NA))) %>%
 ggplot(., aes(x = factor(type), y = fc)) +
    geom_boxplot() + 
 geom_point(size=1.5, aes(x=jitter(as.numeric(type)), color = fc))+
 scale_colour_gradient(low="blue",high="red") +
    geom_text(aes(label = outlier), na.rm = TRUE, hjust = -0.3)
```

I got the figure:[image]

If I add `outlier.size=-1` in the `geom_boxplot()`, I will get:
[image]

But the label is not close to the point which representing. Can someone tell me how to adjust my code? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use `ggbeeswarm` for the points and `ggrepel` for nice labels. 
Of note, remove outliers from the boxplot using `outlier.colour = NA` and subset your data in the `geom_text_repel`

```
d %>% 
  group_by(type) %>%
  mutate(outlier=ifelse(is_outlier(fc),genes,as.numeric(NA))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(type), fc)) + 
    geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = NA) +
    ggbeeswarm::geom_beeswarm(aes(color=fc)) +
    ggrepel::geom_text_repel(data=. %>% filter(!is.na(outlier)), aes(label=genes)) +
    scale_colour_gradient(low="blue",high="red")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplication of [adding text to ggplot geom_jitter points that match a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551147/adding-text-to-ggplot-geom-jitter-points-that-match-a-condition)

You can simply store the jittered values in a separate data frame along with labels and use this data frame inside `geom_point` and `geom_text` for consistency.